# Navigation bar in iOS 6 look like bar in iOS 7

Tags: ios6, ios7, uinavigationbar

Is there any way to make navigation bar elements (back button) in iOS 6 look like navigation bar elements in iOS 7 ?
And also buttons and other iOS 7 elements of UI.

Comment: You can customize the tool bar in IOS 6.

Comment: I know, but is there any easier way? For example i need to use image in back button to make it look like iOS 7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of putting code into every view controller that you need to customize, I would recommend doing this for the entire application by putting something like this in your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method in the App Delegate

```
// Nav bar
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"navBar.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 5, 10, 5)] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

// Back buttons
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backNavButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

// Toolbar
[[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"toolbar.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 5, 10, 5)] forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: Tnx. I will try asap and answer

Comment: It works perfect for me. By the way, what size must be an image to use it as background of back button?

Comment: @KirillBazarov The size is up to you, but typically Apple recommends making the images stretchable (using the `resizableImageWithCapInsets` method that I used in the above example) so they can expand/contract depending on what the back button text says

Comment: Resizable image sample : `UIImage *backImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navback.png"];
        UIImage *resizableBackImg = [backImg resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 12, 0, 1)];//top,left,bottom, right;
        [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:resizableBackImg forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];`

Comment: Just a heads up, you comments are in the wrong order, it should be top right bottom left.

Comment: @smcdrc Sorry I think situee is right, it is top, left, bottom, right

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I need to stop going back and forth between CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the navigation bar by setting the background Image like this

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"topbar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

And you can add a customize bar with setLeftBarButtonItems method like this.

```
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItems:];
```