# Why Bar button item tint color changing in ios 6.0?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios6, uibarbuttonitem

I am making my application support both iOS 6 and iOS 7 .
I am using Xcode 5 with iOS 7 SDK.

When I create the storyboard, the buttons in the navigation bar are in iOS 7 style.

But when I run it in iOS 6.0, it shows tint color in the background as following.
I want the iOS 7 style in iOS 6.
Is there any way to do that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Post some code to decribe how are you creating bar button

Comment: That is the behaviour defined in IOS 6 and 7. You need to check ios version and write seperate code for both IOS 6 & 7.

Comment: Hi Rajath,That is the only solution i am finding.I thought any other thing will do....Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can make **Navigation bar in iOS 6 look like Navigation bar in iOS 7**

Just Go To This link  :

[Navigation bar in iOS 6 look like bar in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19179528/navigation-bar-in-ios-6-look-like-bar-in-ios-7)

And for more information Just Follow [Apple documentation for  iOS 7 UI Transition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/AppearanceCustomization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH15-SW1)